# Cramer-Lundberg: Adjustment coefficient does not exist

Tags: risk, risk-management, insurance

The question is about [Ruin theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruin_theory) and the Cramer-Lundberg model.
I am wondering if there is an example of distribution where the MGF is finite, but the adjustment coefficient does not exist.
Can you help?